# Can istio prevent request infinite loop in the circuit break policy?

Tags: istio, circuit-breaker

How can I configure my circuit breaker to block circular requests between services?

Example:

`serviceA.endpoin1 -> serviceB.endpoin2 -> serviceC.endpoin3 -> serviceA.endpoin1`

> In this scenario `serviceC` will trigger the `serviceA` and will enter in a infinitive loop.
> Note that the endpoint `serviceC.endpoint3` will trigger the initial endpoint `serviceA.endpoint1`. If the `serviceC` is calling another endpoint of `serviceA`, that will not be a problem (or will?).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such function to exist.

What comes to mind is to use [HTTPMatchRequest](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPMatchRequest), preventing requests with particular header to be directed to `serviceA.endpoin1`.
For example applying VirtualService to `serviceA.endpoin1`, to redirect all requests with header `x-original-source: serviceA.endpoin1` to another endpoint.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: <name>
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        x-original-source:
          exact: serviceA.endpoin1
    route:
    - destination:
        host: <some other endpoint different than serviceA.endpoin1>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks.... but in the case of what I really need is a "hop cout", like a "stack overflow"... to prevent something like "a loop/for inside a service, requesting to another services endpoints for each element". Is it possible?

Comment: Nothing like that in Istio, but since it's still up to your application to collect and propagate headers (Istio can not do this by itself), you can implement such feature in your app. Collect data from header, add one, and pass new vaule in a header to next service.

Comment: Can maybe I use a istio envoyfilter https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter to do this? Using lua code, to get the current value of my request, increment, and return it no the response?